# ReentrantReadWriteLock hang

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, reentrantreadwritelock

any idea why this constructor hangs indefinitely? I'm trying to create a thread-safe singleton.

```
private RWLockedSingleton() {
    lock.writeLock().lock();
    System.out.println("we're done!");
    isComplete = true;
    lock.writeLock().unlock();
}
```

BTW, I realize it may be better to place the lock in the static getter; I'm just curious to know whether it's intrinsically wrong to use the lock in a constructor

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. You might also want to ask yourself why you're using `ReentrantReadWriteLock` at all, instead of one of the various patterns which implements a thread-safe singleton without this, using the static initialization guarantees instead.

Comment: It's better to do it this way: `try
{
 lock.writeLock().lock();
 // Do whatever you want to do
}
finally
{
 lock.writeLock().unlock();
}`

Comment: @jon-skeet I read about the static init method but I just wanted to  make the multi-threading explicit in the code.

Comment: @Eddy: It sounds like you're adding complexity (and in a broken way, it seems) for no reason.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO It is almost always incorrect to lock a constructor. There is a good reason you cannot add `synchronized` to a constructor.  You should be locking in the method which calls the constructor.

You can have a writeLock() wait forever if you are holding the readLock(), even if its in the same thread.

The simplest and often the most efficient way to create a lazy loaded, thread safe singleton is to use an `enum`

```
enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

Comment: Waiting forever was indeed the problem I had... thanks for the tip

Comment: Often the simplest solution works best. Using an enum avoids the need for an explicit lock but is still thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

just noticed that in the static getter I acquired a lock on the lock.readLock just before dropping in the constructor.

According to JavaDoc,  if a thread has a reader lock it is not allowed to escalate to a write lock. I would have expected an Exception or Error but there may be valid uses for just stalling the thread until the readLock is unlocked. For reference, the following  won't work if the constructor tries to acquire the writeLock

```
public static RWLockedSingleton getSingleton() {
    lock.readLock().lock();
    RWLockedSingleton ref = null;
    if (singleton == null) {
        singleton = new RWLockedSingleton();
        ref = singleton;
    }
    lock.readLock().unlock();
    return ref;
};
```